# GCC Compiler error: -Werror=stringop-truncation: no option

Tags: c++, cmake, avr-gcc

I am trying to run a gcc compiler to make an executable, but I get this whenever I run the 'make' command in my terminal:

```
Scanning dependencies of target my_libs-atmega328p
[  2%] Building CXX object my_libs/CMakeFiles/my_libs-atmega328p.dir/CLed.cpp.obj
cc1plus: error: -Werror=stringop-truncation: no option -Wstringop-truncation
make[2]: *** [my_libs/CMakeFiles/my_libs-atmega328p.dir/build.make:63:my_libs/CMakeFiles/my_libs-atmega328p.dir/CLed.cpp.obj] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:246: my_libs/CMakeFiles/my_libs-atmega328p.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

I don't even have a string in the file it gets tripped up on (CLed.cpp), so I don't know why it is trying to truncate a string. I have even commented out the entire file and it still is looking for something. Where might I go to find the solution?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please provide the CMake code you use to generate your build system? There may be some clues about the issue in there. If relevant, please provide the commands you use to *run* `cmake` and `make` as well.

Comment: What version of GCC are you using?

Comment: I have gcc 9.2, but my avr-gcc won't update itself beyond 5.4 on linux. Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't even have a string in the file it gets tripped up on (CLed.cpp), so I don't know why it is trying to truncate a string

It is not "trying to truncate a string", nor is it warning about "trying to truncate a string."

The error is saying that the compiler was given the option `-Werror=stringop-truncation` while the compiler does not recognise such warning option. The solution is to not pass `-Werror=stringop-truncation` to the compiler. Or to use another compiler (version) that does support such option.